# How do you know how many Super Sea Snails you have?

Tags: splatoon-2

In Splatoon2, of course you get Super Sea Snails by:

- get one when you level up a ranked level, eg B to B+
- get 20 or so if you play in a Splatfest

and you can use Super Sea Snails in aid of building equipment sets to

- make a slot in gear
- reroll a full gear

But how do you know how many Super Sea Snails you have?!

I cannot find this info anywhere!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It tells you on the [top](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KmNMa.png) right.

[image: top]

Comment: WHOA - having played 1000 hours of Splatoon, I have never noticed that.  Amazing.  Thank you so much!